# Dynamically set meta tags EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am using EJS and I need to set meta tags for every post. I have boilerplate in the layouts folder, which I include on each page. When the user enters the posting page, I need to set dynamic meta tags and title.
My boilerplate

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <% include ../partials/navbar.ejs %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <% include ../partials/filter.ejs %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-10">
                <%- body -%>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
                <% include ../partials/sidebar %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to pass title to the posting page in this way

```
res.render('post/index', {title: post.meta.title, post: post});
```

But I have an error that title is not defined in the boilerplate;

Answer (score 0):

if i understood the problem correctly, i made a sample for you.

mongoose schema for posts

```
const postScheme = new Schema({
 "title": String, 
 "description": String, // meta description
 "robots": String, // index or noindex
 "lang": String, // en, fr, tr
 "pathname": String, // post-pathname
 "main": String // post body content
})
```

Get the post data and rendered.

```
Post.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, data) => {
  res.render('post/index', { 'data': data })
}).lean()
```

and edit .ejs file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="<%= data.lang %>">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> <%= data.title %> </title>
    <meta name="description" content=" <%= data.description %> "/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <% include ../partials/navbar.ejs %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <% include ../partials/filter.ejs %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-10">
                <%- data.main %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
                <% include ../partials/sidebar %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you render `title` variable in all pages? If not that's why you get undefined error. Check for undefined with `locals` object and enclose your variable in title html tags.
In case you don't render a title variable you can set a generic title for the rest of the pages

```
<title> <%= locals.title ? title  : 'Α generic title' %> </title>
```

Comment: I have used this answer for a long time. But for some reason, it does not work when you share the link. It displays an empty preview with just thumbnail and website address.